# Cancellative semigroup on a distributive lattice

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids, counterexamples, lattice-theory

Let $(S,\le)$ be a distributive lattice. Is there a semigroup structure on $S$ such that $S$ is cancellative and always $(x\wedge y)(x\vee y)=xy$?

Comment: What is the motivation and significance of this identity? It doesn’t even imply that it is a lattice-ordered semigroup.

Comment: I hope it can characterize distributivity.

Comment: @EmilJerabek: It is clear that whenever a lattice admits such a semigroup operation, it must be distributive. The opposite implication seems to be tricky.

Comment: @user47958: do you check some lattices $L_n$ (of divisors of $n$)?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: They allow such semigroup structure.

Comment: @user47958: how?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: The lattice of divisors of $n$ is a direct product of linear lattices. For linear lattices, the identity is vacuously true (as long as the semigroup is commutative, which it always has to be), so one can just take e.g. a cyclic group structure on each factor.

Comment: @user47958: do you know a distributive lattice with such a cancellative semigroup structure but without such a group structure?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: take $(\Bbb N,|)$ with mutiplication. I do not know if there's any group structure on it.

Comment: Assuming your $\mathbb N$ doesn’t contain $0$ (otherwise multiplication is not cancellative), $(\mathbb N,|)$ is a direct sum of countably many linear lattices, and as such it has a group structure by the same argument: e.g., let $p_1^{a_1}\dots p_k^{a_k}*p_1^{b_1}\dots p_k^{b_k}=p_1^{f^{-1}(f(a_1)+f(a_2))}\dots p_k^{f^{-1}(f(a_k)+f(b_k))}$, where $f(a)=a/2$ for $a$ even, and $f(a)=-(1+a)/2$ for $a$ odd. Now, what is not clear to me is whether there is any cancellative semigroup structure on $(\mathbb N,|)$ when $\mathbb N$ includes $0$.

Comment: Oh, there is: make $0$ a unit, and put $n*m=2nm$ for $n,m\ne0$.

Comment: Do you require the semigroup operation to be order preserving?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: No ;).

Comment: A finite cancellative semigroup is always a group so is it true that every finite distributive lattice has a group structure with the property you want?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: in finite case, one can replace semigroup with a group in the question above.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: It makes the characterization more probable. But there may be an existential counterexample.

Comment: If the goal is a characterization of distributivity, a simple one in the same vein is as follows. A (finitely additive) measure on a lattice $L$ is a mapping $m\colon L\to A$, where $A$ is an abelian group, and $m(x)+m(y)=m(x\wedge y)+m(x\vee y)$ for all $x,y\in L$. Then $L$ is distributive iff it carries an injective measure. The property in the question is equivalent to the same thing with an extra condition that the image of $m$ be closed under $+$, and any way I look at it, this is an unnatural requirement.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Do you have refrence with a proof for it. Such proof may be useful to for the question.

Comment: That’s an immediate consequence of the fact that every distributive lattice can be embedded in a Boolean algebra. (A Boolean algebra is also an abelian group, in fact, a commutative ring.)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/139828/47958

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exhaustive search confirms that the 18-element lattice of down-sets of the poset
$P=(\{a,b,c,u,v,w\},\{(a,u),(a,v),(b,u),(b,w),(c,v),(c,w)\})$ is a counterexample.

EDIT: I used an ad hoc C program for the check. The code is posted below, but let me first explain how it works.

Let $L$ be a finite distributive lattice. Since the condition in the OP forces the semigroup to be commutative, and finite cancellative semigroups are groups, the condition is equivalent to the existence of an abelian group $A$, and a bijective mapping $\mu\colon L\to A$ satisfying
$$\tag{$*$}\mu(x)+\mu(y)=\mu(x\land y)+\mu(x\lor y),\qquad x,y\in L.$$
By subtracting $\mu(0)$ if necessary, we may assume without loss of generality
$$\tag{${*}{*}$}\mu(0)=0.$$
I will call a mapping $\mu$ satisfying $(*)$ and $(**)$ an $A$-valued measure on $L$. Now, how do such measures look like?

Let $(I,\le)$ be the Birkhoff dual of $L$, i.e., the poset of join-irreducible elements of $L$ under the induced order. $L$ is isomorphic to the lattice $D(I)$ of down-sets of $I$, wherefrom it is easy to see that for any sequence $\{a_i:i\in I\}$ of elements of $A$,
$$\tag{${*}{*}{*}$}\mu(x)=\sum_{i\le x}a_i$$
defines a measure on $L$. On the other hand, let $\mu$ be a measure, and define
$$a_i=\mu(i)-\sum_{\substack{j\in I\\j<i}}a_j$$
by well-founded induction on $i\in I$. Let $\mu'$ be as in $(*{*}*)$. Then $\mu'$ is a measure on $L$ that coincides with $\mu$ on join-irreducible elements. It follows by induction that $\mu(x)=\mu'(x)$ for all $x\in L$: if $x\ne0$ is not join-irreducible, we can write it as $x=y\lor z$ with $y,z<x$, hence
$$\mu(x)=\mu(y)+\mu(z)-\mu(y\land z)=\mu'(y)+\mu'(z)-\mu'(y\land z)=\mu'(x)$$
by the induction hypothesis. Thus, measures on $L$ are exactly the mappings of the form $(*{*}*)$.

In the particular case of $P$, the lattice $D(P)$ has 18 elements, and the only abelian groups of that size are $C_{18}$ and $C_6\times C_3$. The code below does a brute-force search for a sequence $\{a_i:i\in P\}$ such that the corresponding measure $\mu\colon D(P)\to A$ as in $(*{*}*)$ is injective; the choice of $A$ is controlled by uncommenting the appropriate definition of the `A(x,y)` macro (the first line implements addition in $C_{18}$, the second one in $C_6\times C_3$).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define N 18
#define A(x,y) ((x + y) % N)
// #define A(x,y) ((x + y - 3 * (((x % 3) + (y % 3)) >= 3)) % N)

#define TEST(s,x) { unsigned tmp = 1 << (x); if (tmp & s) { cnt++; continue; } s |= tmp; }

int main (void)
{
  unsigned a, cnt = 0;
  for (a = 1; a < N; a++) {
    unsigned b, sa = 1;
    TEST(sa, a);
    for (b = 1; b < N; b++) {
      unsigned c, sb = sa, ab = A(a, b);
      TEST(sb, b);
      TEST(sb, ab);
      for (c = 1; c < N; c++) {
        unsigned u, sc = sb, ac = A(a, c), bc = A(b, c), abc = A(ab, c);
        TEST(sc, c);
        TEST(sc, ac);
        TEST(sc, bc);
        TEST(sc, abc);
        for (u = 1; u < N; u++) {
          unsigned v, su = sc, abu = A(ab, u), abcu = A(abc, u);
          TEST(su, abu);
          TEST(su, abcu);
          for (v = 1; v < N; v++) {
            unsigned w, sv = su, acv = A(ac, v), abcv = A(abc, v), abcuv = A(abcu, v);
            TEST(sv, acv);
            TEST(sv, abcv);
            TEST(sv, abcuv);
            for (w = 1; w < N; w++) {
              unsigned sw = sv, bcw = A(bc, w), abcw = A(abc, w), abcuw = A(abcu, w), abcvw = A(abcv, w), abcuvw = A(abcuv, w);
              TEST(sw, bcw);
              TEST(sw, abcw);
              TEST(sw, abcuw);
              TEST(sw, abcvw);
              TEST(sw, abcuvw);
              assert (sw == (1 << N) - 1);
              printf ("%u,%u,%u;%u,%u,%u\n", a, b, c, u, v, w);
              return 1;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  printf ("no (%u)\n", cnt);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that a computer program can check that it is really a counterexample?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I first tried to do it by hand with various tricks, but it got way too messy, and it turns out that a dumb computer search works like a charm.

Comment: Which program did you use (gap, wolfram, etc)? Do I need to write a proram from scratch (eg with C++)?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: respect!

Comment: http://cpp.sh/4l2